# Python regex, how to replace multiple groups from multiple matches

Tags: python

I have a hunch I'm not seeing the simple solution to this so before I tear my hair out, maybe some one can help.

This is a bit of code:

```
gr = regex.compile(r'({[^{]*(?>{[^{}]+})*)\s\\over\s([^{}]+(?>{[^{}]*})*})')
string1 = "{a \over b}"
string2 = "{x \over b{x}} {{d}d \over x}}"

m = regex.match(gr,string2)

reLine = regex.sub(gr,r"\\test"+m.group(1)+"}{"+m.group(2),string2)
```

The objective is basically this:

```
before {a \over b}
after \test{a}{b}
```

And I have to look through the text file and replace all these matches.

My problem is with regex.search or regex.match it only matches once and returns one match with its groups, but I need multiple matches in case {a \over b} repeats multiple times on the same line.

So with 'string2' it captures '{x' as the first group, 'b{x}}' as the second, and stops capturing. So then when I try to replace, it replaces the groups of the first match with the second '\over' equation as well.

I have practiced regular expressions on regexr.com and it has a 'replace' function. It takes all the matches and replaces ($1,$2) all the matches and groups respectively.

Am I missing something on python regex module? Or is this problem more complicated than I imagined?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the `regex.fiindAll` / `regex.finditer` ?

Comment: I'm quite aware of these methods, but how would I use these with regex.sub AND then replace it into the string's correct place?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone interested:
After some thought I solved my own problem by using regex.split.

I split the whole line by catching wider matches, and then replacing each match individually.